# Can different departure procedures have different transition altitudes at the same aerodrome?

Tags: approach, altitude, flight-level

Is it possible for operations and ATC to have different departures procedures with different transition altitudes at a single aerodrome? For example:

1. SID RWY11 with a transition altitude of 2,000 meter
2. SID RWY29 with a transition altitude of 2,500 meter

Comment: What country/jurisdiction are you referring to?

Comment: It is not established in the real world.

Comment: I've just never heard of a transition alt being tied to an approach procure

Comment: Yea, I have never too. One of the procedure designers has just sent me(cartographer) a draft version of approach procedure. Then logically, I rejected the procedure due to that Transition altitude.

Comment: IIRC the transition attitude can never be lower than 3000ft

Comment: what do you mean with transition altitude. On an approach you are coming from above, so the transition altitude should not matter to you, transition **level** is what matters. I suspect you mean something different. Do you mean the altitude at which you fly before you intercept the glideslope?

Comment: @DeltaLima In my Country, most of aerodromes do not have SID-ICAO. So Transition altitude is shown IAC-ICAO. That is why i asked that way, i have just edited question into correct way to ask,

Comment: So are we talking about when to switch to QFE here or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The transition attitude in a defined area is fixed. For example, in the USA it is 18.000ft and in many European countries it is 5.000ft. It's impossible to have different transition altitudes at one airport, because that would make it impossible to use vertical separation between aircraft close to the transition layer.

Comment: +1 for mentioning it has nothing to do with a single airport. However, I suppose the transition altitude can vary inside one country (in different regions), can't it? In large countries with a variety of terrains like China or India, it would make sense...

Comment: @mins Interesting, I've always thought it's primarily defined by area and not by airport.

Comment: @mins, “varies from airport to airport” does not necessarily imply that it has anything to do with the airport itself. Every airport is in some sector and if it varies between sectors, it varies between airports too.

Answer (score 3):

ICAO PAN-OPS (v1) 2.1.2.2: "Where two or more closely spaced aerodromes are located so that coordinated procedures are required, a common transition altitude shall be established. This common transition altitude shall be the highest that would be required if the aerodromes were considered separately." – mins 2 days ago

This comment should be the answer for me. Thanks all, Everything wroten here is useful information.